# Does Vladimir's Sanguine Pool have a hidden movement speed buff?

Tags: league-of-legends

The description for Vladimir's Sanguine Pool is:

> (Active): Vladimir sinks into a pool of blood becoming untargetable
>   for 2 seconds and slowing enemies above him by 40% for 1 second.
>   Additionally, he deals magic damage every half second to them and
>   heals himself for 12.5% of the damage done.

Nowhere in the description does it describe any sort of movement speed buff yet when I see a Vladimir use his pool it feels like he is moving faster. But because I don't own Vladimir I was never really able to test it out.

Now earlier I was looking at the last large patch update and I see this:

> Vladimir - Sanguine Pool: movement speed bonus now decays over time.

So my question is: Is there a hidden movement speed buff on Vladimir's Sanguine Pool and if so, how much is the movement speed buff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**,

In [Sanguine Pool's ability detail](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details#Sanguine_Pool) (5th bullet point), it states,

> Even though not stated in the tooltip, Sanguine Pool also gives Vladimir a **37.5% movement speed boost for 1 second** upon activating the ability.

---

This supports [doomy's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77831/20893).

Answer (score 2):

From what I hear it gives a 37.5% movement speed buff lasting a second.
[As stated in the comment section of this page.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper)

Answer (score 0):

Its not REALLY hidden, its just the same thing with Lulu: If he is in Sanguine Pool and he moves with exactly the same MS, it would look bad cause his model gets bigger and he would actually move SLOWER cause he doesnt get out of it in the middle of the pool, not at the edge. Lulus squirrel ability has the same thing, when you turn someone into a squirrel, he gets a soft slow as well, cause it simply wouldn't look correctly if he would proceed to move with the exact same speed

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Plus how is it not hidden where there is a buff that the skill description doesn't show. For your example of Lulu's Whimsey, the skill description actually shows the movement reduction.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with this at all...Vlads pool says in-game and on mobafire in the description that it clearly gives you a speed buff...what you're talking about is, well idk what it is lol

Answer (score 0):

The speed buff on this isn't hidden at all, I was just going to comment this but this can be answer as well.  When you look at a champion in game from your owned champion list it gives a very vague description of what an ability does, it does this for all of them, it doesn't tell the AP / AD / Health scaling, or base damage as you level it, none of that, just as vlads sanguine pool doesn't mention the movement speed increase (I assume is where you were looking).  I'll tell you neat thing I do to find out all the details of an ability.

Go to google, and type in (champion name [i.e. vladimir, or ahri, or malphite]) then guide.  The first link in google will always appear from mobafire, click it, then the top link on that page being the first guide.  Right under the runes and purchase order for this guide is a list with all the abilities set up for what level you should acquire them, mousing over each ability (level doesn't matter) will bring up a 100% better explanation of the move than Riot gives you in your champion list, it tells the base damage and increase per level, all effects of the spell, scaling with AP / AD / Health, everything you could need to know (duration of slow / stun as well).

So if you need any further knowledge on any champion ability on any champion, just follow these instructions to get an in depth description on any ability.  Hope this was of help.

Comment: That's not true. Although it doesn't list the exact number for the ap / ad/ health scaling it still shows the base damage plus the bonus damage from scaling in game. And all the other skills that reduce or increase movement speed is in its description. And you didn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I play vlad quite a bit and i've never noticed a movement speed buff in his pool form, perhaps the patch notes meant that the movement speed debuff from his pool recovers over time?